# How do I add ONLY specific DB Entity Sets to the ViewData in ASP.NET MVC 4 Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, viewdata

I am attempting to populate my ViewData with ONLY specific DB Entity Sets in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project.  Below is what I have so far, but how do I write this "if" statment to accomplish this?

```
 public PartialViewResult _GetforSelectedStatus(string TargetName)
 {
      _selectedJobDB = new IntegrationDBEntities();
      foreach (Job j in _selectedJobDB.Jobs)
      {
           if (j.Request.TargetName == TargetName)
           {
                //I need to add the Job that meets the above "if" requirment to the ViewData here....
           }
      }
 }
```

Normally I have been then sending the ViewData Model to the partial view as below, but I don't think this will work since I am not wanting to send the whole model:

```
 ViewData.Model = _selectedJobDb.Jobs.ToList();
 return PartialView();
```

How do I add  ONLY specific DB Entity Sets to the ViewData and send this to the PartialView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewData.Model = _selectedJobDb.Jobs.Where(j => j.Request.TargetName == TargetName).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank You!  I am trying it now.  Can you please ive my question an up vote?

Comment: Hmmm...  It isn't doing what I wanted, but I think I may have a problem with my Ajax.

Comment: @antman1p: Don't ask for upvotes. If someone thinks that you wrote a well-reasoned, good question that clearly explains the problem and what you hope to achieve, then they will upvote it. However, that's not a condition for *answering* a question. Just because Andrey wrote an answer doesn't mean he thinks your question was any good.

Comment: @Chris Pratt, I don't know if you've noticed, but there is a lot of non-upvoting going on.  The question was asked clearly.  It was answerable.  What else constitutes a good question?  I always ask for upvotes.  On the other hand I always upvote a clearly written and understandable question.  If the solution works, I chekc the answer.

Comment: The problem is that it shifts the focus. If I see someone asking for upvotes, I'm thinking you're just after rep. That may not be the case, but it creates a bad impression. Not to brag, but I've accumulated quite a bit of rep and never asked for an upvote once. If you write good questions and answers and just generally participate in the community, rep comes naturally.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm not much for answering questions, but I ask alot.  I'm pretty new, so I don't have much to offer, though I do look for questions I can answer.  It just seems that I ask a lot of questions that haven't been asked before.  I take the time to write them clearly and ensure that I add just the right amount of detail.  The rep doesn't matter to me except to ensure I can still access chat rooms.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it isn't calling my view now.  For some reason I can't debug the view anymore either.